XSLT 1.0 Recursive template call in XML Transformation
The HandlingUnitItem (/HandlingUnit/HandlingUnitItem/HandlingUnit/HandlingUnitItem) in the XML path getting repeated in the XML output. I'm not able to figure out why it was getting repeated in the Output.
I'm attaching the Input XML, XSLT code and the Output XML for your reference. exslt:node-set($Contents) what's  this Content variable is holding?
Input xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
            <TKNUM>0001960714</TKNUM>
            <SHTYP>DEFC</SHTYP>
            <ABFER>1</ABFER>
            <ABWST>1</ABWST>
            <BFART>2</BFART>
            <VSART>01</VSART>
            <LAUFK>4</LAUFK>
            <VSBED>VL</VSBED>
            <STTRG>7</STTRG>
            <DTMEG>KGM</DTMEG>
            <DTMEV>DMQ</DTMEV>
            <DISTZ>0.000</DISTZ>
            <FAHZT>0.00</FAHZT>
            <GESZT>0.00</GESZT>
            <STERM_DONE>X</STERM_DONE>
            <GESZTD>0</GESZTD>
            <FAHZTD>0</FAHZTD>
            <GESZTDA>0</GESZTDA>
            <FAHZTDA>0</FAHZTDA>
            <WARZTD>0</WARZTD>
            <WARZTDA>0</WARZTDA>
            <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                <VBELN>0076668882</VBELN>
                <VSTEL>DCXX</VSTEL>
                <VKORG>DDDD</VKORG>
                <LGNUM>DC1</LGNUM>
                <ABLAD>RHLZM</ABLAD>
                <INCO1>FCA</INCO1>
                <INCO2>LANG</INCO2>
                <ROUTE>DE0005</ROUTE>
                <VSBED>VL</VSBED>
                <BTGEW>1.601</BTGEW>
                <NTGEW>1.584</NTGEW>
                <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                <VOLUM>0.005</VOLUM>
                <VOLEH>MTQ</VOLEH>
                <ANZPK>00001</ANZPK>
                <TRATY>031</TRATY>
                <PARID>44284</PARID>
                <PODAT>20240715</PODAT>
                <POTIM>132944</POTIM>
                <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                    <EXIDV>00000000000109126078</EXIDV>
                    <TARAG>0.001</TARAG>
                    <GWEIT>KGM</GWEIT>
                    <BRGEW>0.001</BRGEW>
                    <NTGEW>0.000</NTGEW>
                    <city1>0.000</city1>
                    <GWEIM>KGM</GWEIM>
                    <BTVOL>0.005</BTVOL>
                    <NTVOL>0.005</NTVOL>
                    <MAVOL>0.000</MAVOL>
                    <VOLEM>MTQ</VOLEM>
                    <TAVOL>0.000</TAVOL>
                    <VOLET>MTQ</VOLET>
                    <VHILM>PM-3215</VHILM>
                    <LAENG>0.000</LAENG>
                    <BREIT>0.000</BREIT>
                    <HOEHE>0.000</HOEHE>
                    <MEABM>MTR</MEABM>
                    <VHART>ZMBE</VHART>
                    <MAGRV>0003</MAGRV>
                    <LADLG>0</LADLG>
                    <FARZT>0</FARZT>
                    <ENTFE>0</ENTFE>
                    <VELTP>C</VELTP>
                    <VHILM_KU>KC2</VHILM_KU>
                    <VEBEZ>VDA-KLT R 3215</VEBEZ>
                    <SMGKN>S</SMGKN>
                    <KDMAT35>KC2</KDMAT35>
                    <ERNAM>WMALEREMOTE</ERNAM>
                    <GEWFX>X</GEWFX>
                    <EXIDA>B</EXIDA>
                    <MOVE_STATUS>0050</MOVE_STATUS>
                    <ZUL_AUFL>           0.000</ZUL_AUFL>
                    <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                        <MAGRV_BEZ>Ben</MAGRV_BEZ>
                        <VEBEZ>VDA</VEBEZ>
                    </E1EDL38>
                    <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                        <VBELN>0076668882</VBELN>
                        <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                        <VEMNG>1600.000</VEMNG>
                        <VEMEH>PCE</VEMEH>
                        <MATNR>8993601404</MATNR>
                        <WERKS>DCXX</WERKS>
                        <LGORT>S002</LGORT>
                        <CUOBJ>000000000000000000</CUOBJ>
                        <ANZSN>         0</ANZSN>
                        <WDATU>00000000</WDATU>
                    </E1EDL44>
                </E1EDL37>
                <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                    <EXIDV>00000000000109126079</EXIDV>
                    <TARAG>0.000</TARAG>
                    <GWEIT>KGM</GWEIT>
                    <BRGEW>1.614</BRGEW>
                    <NTGEW>1.614</NTGEW>
                    <city1>0.000</city1>
                    <GWEIM>KGM</GWEIM>
                    <BTVOL>0.005</BTVOL>
                    <NTVOL>0.005</NTVOL>
                    <MAVOL>0.000</MAVOL>
                    <VOLEM>MTQ</VOLEM>
                    <TAVOL>0.000</TAVOL>
                    <VOLET>MTQ</VOLET>
                    <VHILM>PM-9999</VHILM>
                    <LAENG>0.000</LAENG>
                    <BREIT>0.000</BREIT>
                    <HOEHE>0.000</HOEHE>
                    <MEABM>MTR</MEABM>
                    <INHALT>040578630025545457</INHALT>
                    <VHART>0003</MAGRV>
                    <LADLG>0</LADLG>
                    <FARZT>0</FARZT>
                    <ENTFE>0</ENTFE>
                    <VELTP>C</VELTP>
                    <EXIDV2>040578630025545457</EXIDV2>
                    <VEBEZ>**********************</VEBEZ>
                    <SMGKN>M</SMGKN>
                    <ERNAM>WMALEREMOTE</ERNAM>
                    <GEWFX>X</GEWFX>
                    <EXIDA>B</EXIDA>
                    <MOVE_STATUS>0050</MOVE_STATUS>
                    <ZUL_AUFL>0.000</ZUL_AUFL>
                    <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VHART_BEZ>Palette</VHART_BEZ>
                        <MAGRV_BEZ>Ben</MAGRV_BEZ>
                        <VEBEZ>**********************</VEBEZ>
                    </E1EDL38>
                    <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                        <VELIN>3</VELIN>
                        <EXIDV>00000000000109126078</EXIDV>
                    </E1EDL44>
                </E1EDL37>
            </E1EDL20>
        </E1EDT20>
    </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>

XSLT Code :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/*/IDOC/E1EDT20">
                <xsl:for-each select="/*/IDOC/E1EDT20|/*/IDOC[E1EDL20]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20/E1EDL37[not(EXIDV=/*/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/E1EDL37/E1EDL44/EXIDV)]">
                        <xsl:sort select="EXIDV"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EXIDV"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="HUTree"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="HUTree">
        <HandlingUnit>
            <xsl:attribute name="key">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(VHILM,VHILM_KU,SMGKN,LAENG,BREIT,HOEHE,BRGEW,NTGEW,GWEIM)"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL44|E1EDT43">
                    <xsl:sort select="VELIN" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="MATNR"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(VELIN,EXIDV,MATNR,VBELN,POSNR,VEMNG,VEMEH,KDMAT)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="EXIDV|VHILM|VHILM_KU|SMGKN|LAENG|BREIT|HOEHE|BRGEW|NTGEW|GWEIM"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Contents">
                <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL44|E1EDT43">
                    <xsl:sort select="VELIN" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="MATNR"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="VBELN" select="VBELN"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="POSNR" select="POSNR"/>
                    <HandlingUnitItem>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="VELIN|MATNR|VBELN|POSNR|VEMNG|VEMEH|KDMAT"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/*/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20[VBELN=$VBELN]/E1EDL24[POSNR=$POSNR]/E1EDL41[QUALI='001']/BSTNR"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="../../E1EDL20/E1EDL37[EXIDV=current()/EXIDV] | ../../../E1EDL20/E1EDL37[EXIDV=current()/EXIDV]">
                            <xsl:sort select="EXIDV"/>
                            <xsl:call-template name="HUTree"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </HandlingUnitItem>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$Contents"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($Contents)/HandlingUnitItem[not(HandlingUnit/@key=preceding-sibling::HandlingUnitItem/HandlingUnit/@key)]">
                <HandlingUnitItem>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="VELIN|MATNR|VBELN|POSNR|VEMNG|VEMEH|KDMAT|BSTNR"/>
                    <xsl:if test="HandlingUnit">
                        <HandlingUnit>
                            <xsl:variable name="str">
                                <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::HandlingUnitItem[HandlingUnit/@key=current()/HandlingUnit/@key]">
                                    <xsl:if test="position()!=1 and HandlingUnit/EXIDV!=preceding-sibling::HandlingUnitItem[HandlingUnit/@key=current()/HandlingUnit/@key][1]/HandlingUnit/EXIDV+1">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(HandlingUnit/EXIDV,',')"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <OutputStr>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
                            </OutputStr>
                        </HandlingUnit>
                    </xsl:if>
                </HandlingUnitItem>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </HandlingUnit>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output xml :
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
00000000000109126079<HandlingUnit key="PM-9999M0.0000.0000.0001.6141.614KGM300000000000109126078">
    <EXIDV>00000000000109126079</EXIDV>
    <BRGEW>1.614</BRGEW>
    <NTGEW>1.614</NTGEW>
    <GWEIM>KGM</GWEIM>
    <VHILM>PM-9999</VHILM>
    <LAENG>0.000</LAENG>
    <BREIT>0.000</BREIT>
    <HOEHE>0.000</HOEHE>
    <SMGKN>M</SMGKN>
    <HandlingUnitItem>
        <VELIN>3</VELIN>
        <HandlingUnit key="PM-3215KC2S0.0000.0000.0000.0010.000KGM1899360140400766688820000101600.000PCE">
            <EXIDV>00000000000109126078</EXIDV>
            <BRGEW>0.001</BRGEW>
            <NTGEW>0.000</NTGEW>
            <GWEIM>KGM</GWEIM>
            <VHILM>PM-3215</VHILM>
            <LAENG>0.000</LAENG>
            <BREIT>0.000</BREIT>
            <HOEHE>0.000</HOEHE>
            <VHILM_KU>KC2</VHILM_KU>
            <SMGKN>S</SMGKN>
            <HandlingUnitItem>
                <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                <VBELN>0076668882</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                <VEMNG>1600.000</VEMNG>
                <VEMEH>PCE</VEMEH>
                <MATNR>8993601404</MATNR>
                <BSTNR>0057328890010</BSTNR>
            </HandlingUnitItem>
            <HandlingUnitItem>
                <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                <VBELN>0076668882</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                <VEMNG>1600.000</VEMNG>
                <VEMEH>PCE</VEMEH>
                <MATNR>8993601404</MATNR>
                <BSTNR>0057328890010</BSTNR>
            </HandlingUnitItem>
        </HandlingUnit>
    </HandlingUnitItem>
    <HandlingUnitItem>
        <VELIN>3</VELIN>
        <HandlingUnit>
            <OutputStr>00000000000109126078,</OutputStr>
        </HandlingUnit>
    </HandlingUnitItem>
</HandlingUnit>


Please reduce the code examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem ( see: [mcve]) and add the expected result.

When your code samples need scrolling to view them, you greatly reduce the chance that anyone is prepared to make the effort. Especially when the code is full of cryptic element names like GWEIM and VHILM. Simplifying the problem to its bare essentials not only means you're more likely to get an answer: very often it means you will find the answer yourself in the process.

Hi @MichaelKay
This is not the complete XSLT code, I've only posted a part of it. It involves recursive template call, and an xml is created inside the HUTree template. The variable $Contents is defined to hold  elements and while displaying the output of that variable, duplicate  tags appear in the output xml.

Thanks for the extra information, but I'm not motivated to help you with this problem. I would happily do so if you made the effort to simplify it and make a complete but minimal reproducible example.
